# Showing prefilled contact screen to user on android 1.6

Tags: android, contacts

I have got following project requirment.

When user has given `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`permission in his manifest then we should add contact programatically. ( This part is done and working perfectly).

Now the challenge is If user has not given this permission then i will not able to add contact programatically but the best effort i want to put is show him prefilled contact screen and let him press add button.

**I got this working on Android 2.0 and up.But I am facing issue to make it work on android 1.6 device.**

Below is the code which works on Android 2.0 and up.

```
        Intent i = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Vipul Shah");
        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "1234");

        startActivity(i);
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Android 1.6 accounts for less than 1% of Android devices. Do you really need to support it?

Comment: @RaghavSood Yeah i have to support it.I am always unfortunate when it comes to 1.6 and Client is still want to provide support to 1.6 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `ContactsContract` is only present in API5+ (Android 2.0) environments.

The relevant class in pre-API5 is called [`Contacts`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.html)

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 5)
    Intent i = new Intent(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.ACTION,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Vipul Shah");
    i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "1234");

    startActivity(i);
} else {
    Intent i = new Intent(Contacts.Intents.Insert.ACTION,
             People.CONTENT_URI);
    i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME, "Vipul Shah");
    i.putExtra(Contacts.Intents.Insert.PHONE, "1234");

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but it is crashing on Android 1.6.